# Written File from Node Scrape Incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I am trying to pull the name, address, and url from the madeinnyc tech map for a personal project in learning how to use mapbox. In the process I wanted to scrape the listings and export them in a json file that I could use for the project. The issue I am running into is that the information is not being correctly written to the json file. When I log the scrapped data in the console, I am receiving the correct format and all of the data, but the written file from the scrapped data is incorrect and only received one random piece of data. I think the current setup is scraping individual pieces and overwriting it multiple times, because I am getting multiple `File Success` logs in my console. Is my `writeFile` method incorrect?

Here is the info logged to the console `console.log(metadata)` (correct data, condensed since you get the idea of the rest of the listings):

```
{ name: 'Todayships',
  address: '4447 Seton Ave 2',
  url: 'http://todayships.com/' }
{ name: 'Togather',
  address: '45 Main St Suite 404',
  url: 'http://www.togather.com' }
{ name: 'Tomorrow Networks, LLC',
  address: '1270 Avenue of the Americas 2920',
  url: 'http://www.tomorrownetworks.com' }
{ name: 'Topi',
  address: '20 W 20 Street 2nd Floor',
  url: 'http://topi.com' }
```

output.json

```
{
    "name": "Berlinica Publishing LLC",
    "address": "255 West 43rd Street Suite 1012",
    "url": "http://www.berlinica.com"
}s.com"
}ackground.html"
}drianyc.com/ersp.html"
}
```

scrape.js

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

request('http://mappedinny.com/', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $('li').each(function(i, element){

        var li = $(this)


        var name = li.attr('data-name');
        var address = li.attr('data-address');
        var url = li.attr('data-url');


        var metadata = {
            name : name,
            address : address,
            url : url
        };
        console.log(metadata);

        fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 4), function(err){
                console.log('File Success');
        });

    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're asynchronously writing to the same file in a synchronous loop (your `each()`).

If your intention is to write all results to the same file, you might try:

```
var results = [];

$('li').each(function(i, element){

  var li = $(this)

  var name = li.attr('data-name');
  var address = li.attr('data-address');
  var url = li.attr('data-url');


  var metadata = {
    name : name,
    address : address,
    url : url
  };
  console.log(metadata);

  results.push(metadata);

});

fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(results, null, 4), function(err){
  if (err)
    console.log('File Error: ' + err);
  else
    console.log('File Success');
});
```